# php preg_match with email validation issue

Tags: php

I am validating email address using php with `preg_match` function. But I keep getting following error

```
preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found
```

here is my pattern for preg_match

```
$pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Related: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use:

```
$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i";
```

Comment: This is not fully valid, because you can send email to Martin.Kudlacek@example.com and your pattern would say this address is invalid. Just happened to me in combination with MS Exchange which creates such email addresses.

Comment: @mkudlacek You want to lowercase the email before applying the pattern.

Comment: That's not an answer to the original question. The question is how to validate with preg_match(). The correct pattern would be: /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/ or extended with /i for case insensitive matching.

Comment: @mkudlacek Fair enough. I've added the `i` at the end.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe using

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Would be an easier approach.

Comment: Be careful of using filter_var on email with [IDN domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email)! For example such working emails: путин@президент.рф  or 用户@例子.广告 will be treated as incorrect. You will need idn_to_ascii() function.

Answer (score 8):

use this code

```
<?php
 $email = "asd/sdff@asdf.com"; 
 $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
 $email = (preg_match($regex, $email))?$email:"invalid email";
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't match domains like .agency.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the issues caused by FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL (for instance it doesn't work well with not-latin characters), I prefer to use:

`preg_match("/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i",$email_address);`

Answer (score 1):

Updated the pattern to also allow addresses like `name.surname+t3st@gmail.com`

```
$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function filter_var() in PHP would only be easier if a postmaster wanted to allow an RFC style match for e-mail addresses. For some applications or MTAs (sendmail, etc...), this might not be desirable. However, if one is to go the preg_match() route, I would suggest investigating non-greedy quantifiers and capture statements that do not use buffers. A good place to start would be https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php .

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple email validation method with regex:

```
public function emailValidation($email) 
{
    $regex = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,10})$/";
    $email = strtolower($email);

    return preg_match ($regex, $email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "^" after $ at the end :

```
$pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    var emailid = $.trim($('#emailid').val());  
  if( ! /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailid)){
                alert("<?php echo "email_invalid" ?>");

                return false;
            }
```

## emailid is the id of the input tag